# What is the relationship between the matrix norm and singular value decomposition?

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition, singular-values

I have the following question I am trying to answer but I am constantly failing to.

Given $P \in R^{n \times n}$ with $P = U \Sigma V^T$ being its decomposition, what is $||P||^p_p$ ?

I'm trying to understand what's the specific relationship between SVD and a matrix's p-norm.

As far as I tried to follow, I think this relationship applies only to 2-norm, but I am not sure.

Can anybody please give me a hint on how should I tackle the issue?

Thank you!